# Reload! rails app without closing rails console or objects instantiated within it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I am using Rails Console to help me muck around with an object instance running a Watir browser instance.

I've had to navigate via watir through various forms to get to where I want to thus I don't want to have to recreate the object and browser instance everytime I want to see the effects of changed code I'm wriring.

`reload!` doesn't seem to do the trick for me, confirmed for e.g. through changing proposed browser field text input in the code, calling `reload!` in the active rails console session and calling a method, the old text still used from before the `reload!`.

Is there a way to reload so that I can use uodated code on the already created objects in the already running rails console session?

Thanks

Comment: NO .. there is no way you cannot retain the instantiated objects, because once you `reload!` the app, the whole app boots into a new state with the latest updates in your application's codebase.

Comment: @sa77 that's not totally correct, is it? You can retain the already instantiated objects, but they will not respond to the new code

Comment: Thank you @sa77, perhaps there's a better way of me playing with a long Watir crawling form filling processes, such as saving static html files and writing code whilst testing against them, only to go live once the bulk of the code is written.

Comment: @m.simonborg yes that's the case .. thanks for picking that .. cheers !

Comment: @jbk you can try rails console in sandbox mode to experiment with your app and revert everything once you exit it `rails console --sandbox` [link for more info](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console)